# A submanifold of vector bundle whose intersection with each $E_p$ is linear subspace of same dimension is a subbundle?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I am learning the theory of smooth manifolds using the book *Introduction to Smooth manifolds* by John M. Lee, the definition of smooth subbundle in the book is as follows:

Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle, if $S\subset M$ is an embedded submanifold of $E$ whose intersection with $E_p=\pi^{-1}(p)$ is a linear subspace of $E_p$ for $\forall p\in M$ and $\pi|_S:S\to M$ is a smooth vector bundle, then $\pi|_S:S\to M$ is called a subbundle.

My question is: if $S\subset M $ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ and $S\cap E_p$ is a linear subspace of $E_p$ with the same dimension $m$ for $\forall p\in M$, is $\pi|_S:S\to M$ a subbundle? If the answer is no, could you give a counterexample, because I think this is counterintuitive. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume that your fiber $E_p$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ or something nice like that, and not, say, over $F_2$, the field of two elements, right?

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, I assume $E$ is a real vector bundle, thank you for reminding.